# Logging in to stack sites requires full login process

Tags: discussion, login, cookies

Whenever I try to go to a new stack site, and choose "Stack Exchange" there with google and whatever else, it autopopulates my Username and PW.

When I press enter, it says "Invalid email address". When I change from the username to the email address, it says "No account with this email found."

But I can open a tab, go directly to a stack site that I've used in the past, and there in my profile info it shows the email that I just tried to use where it acted like I was a moron.

In the past, when I've gone to a stack site, it sees the info to other sites, and I get something like "click here to login using your stack exchange account."

how do I make this work like it's suppose to or used to?

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* a [Stack Exchange OpenID](http://openid.stackexchange.com/). You can [get one](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) if you want (and even use the same email you're already using), or you can just click the "log in with Google" button if that's what you used in the past.

Assuming you're not blocking anything important to the process (stackauth.com...), autologin should work just fine once you've authenticated again somewhere.

Comment: so the Stack Exchange option is basically external OAUTH? It's not an internal retrieval of data from SE or other used SE sites? In other words, if YOU decided to go to an AREA 51 site, you'd ahve to login from scratch using whatever OAUTH? If that's the case, did I just imagine it doing what I thought it did? Last thing, do you think it's possible that I could ask any more questions?

Comment: We have a system that'll log you in automatically *if* you're authenticated with the network (go [here](http://stackexchange.com/) - do you see your username at the top of the page)? This uses the domain http://stackauth.com to mediate between sites, however it's still possible to be logged in on *some* sites without having the necessary network-wide authentication for the auto-login to work. If you've *never* logged into a particular site before, you'll always have to authenticate of course.

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, your whole post is in contradiction. First thing, the "system that'll log you in automatically" (yes I see my nick up there on that page) answers one of my questions. The closing statement then says "always have to authenticate" which also answers the same question albeit with the opposite answer. Not trying to be a Hat, just pointing out the confusion.

Comment: It's a confusing system, and yeah I'm probably not doing it any favors here! If it helps, think of it this way: you always have to log in everywhere... BUT! There's a bit of logic that'll try to do it for you when you visit a site. It won't work if you don't already have a profile on that site, it won't work if the network can't figure out that you're logged in, and *sometimes* it won't work for other reasons too (but I'm leaving those out here because this is confusing enough already). If you're able to log in manually, do that - consider auto-logins to be sort of a bonus (at least right now)

Comment: FWIW, you haven't logged in anywhere since February 3rd - I expect something has just expired.

Comment: Bonus as opposed to Feature. Got it. "Ok great... important safety tip. Thanks, Egon."

Comment: I keep coming back to this. I still don't understand how it's supposed to work as it seems to work differently almost everytime I enter a new site. OTOH, it seems that you don't quite have a handle on it either which is fine. It's merely a system spanning hundreds of sites and millions of user accounts... nothing more (=